# "Unable to locate package" When installing in Terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line

When I install softwares in Terminal it says

> Unable to locate package(The name of the software that I'm installing)

a lot of times, what do I do? I use Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: please provide us with more information. How are you installing it? What commands do you use? etc. Better just copy the complete output from the terminal and add it to your question.

Comment: its too long i cant send it in one comment

Comment: That's why you [edit] it into your answer, highlight it and press `ctrl` + `k`.

Comment: ceibal@ceibal:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 Latest stable release of OBS Studio
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~obsproject/+archive/ubuntu/obs-studio
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp_aYAw5/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp_aYAw5/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key F425E228 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmp_aYAw5/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created

Comment: gpg: key F425E228: public key "Launchpad PPA for obsproject" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK

Comment: just wait i will send u the rest

Comment: What are you trying to install, Emily?

Comment: The PPA that you linked in your comment does not appear to contain any packages for Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) - only for Utopic/Trusty/Vivid

Comment: I was trying to install... OBS the screen recorder called Open Broadcaster i THINK

Comment: When I install almost everything it says Unable to locate package

Comment: You probably need to upgrade to 14.04 LTS if you can.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I do but I can't

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The PPA you are using is not available for Ubuntu 12.04.

(From comments:you are using `ppa:obsproject/obs-studio`)

Please refer here : [ubuntu/obs-studio](https://launchpad.net/~obsproject/+archive/ubuntu/obs-studio).

On the official site https://obsproject.com/download#linux
you can see that obs is available for 14.04/15.04+ only.

So to install obs you need to upgrade your Ubuntu system.

Comment: What is PPA? And I can't upgrade my computer...

Comment: `ppa:obsproject/obs-studio`...@EmilyShan

Comment: Huh? Still don't get it...

Comment: Alright,feel free to accept it as answer...Your Q:What are PPA's then Ans: [what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)